# How to display the data from the url of node.js server to a html page

Tags: html, node.js

In this url http://localhost:3000/retrieve.txt, I have the data like this:

```
192.168.7.102,192.168.7.123
```

Then how to display this data into a text box of html page using node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is your backend. It cannot directly alter the contents of an HTML page. This will be done by your frontend i.e. the page itself. But the page needs to get the data from the backend.

What Node.js can do is:

- read the file (either through an http request to `http://localhost:3000/retrieve.txt` or by open the file locally with `fs` module functions)
- parse the contents of the file
- setup a REST endpoint (using [ExpressJs](http://expressjs.com/)  or any other web framework) that will serve this data to whoever does a GET request there

Your frontend (HTML page) will then need to make an XHR (using jQuery is always a quick'n'easy choice) to this REST endpoint to get the data and then place it in the corresponding DOM element.

Comment: K fine.Actually I had sample.html page which has "ip" field.OnClick of "ip" field is redirecting to index.html page.There I'm selecting some checkboxes and the selected values are stored in the client_ip field of the index. html page.Now I'm trying to send the selected values of client_ip field of index.html page to the ip field of sample.html page.I got strucked in sending the values from page to other .How can I do this